# WebPack HMR - run code if HMR server is not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-hmr, hot-module-replacement

I got this basic Javascript code which is compiled by webpack. I am using Hot Module Replacement for Styles and Javascript.
When I listen to `https://localhost:3000/mypage` everything works perfectly.
However I would like the `app()` to run if the HMR can not connect:

`GET http://localhost/__bud/hmr 404 (Not Found)`

I am aware, that in this case my updates will not be applied.
This does currently work, however I have the feeling that it is not the correct way to do this.

My setup is:

- WSL2 - Ubuntu
- Wordpress 6.0
- bud.js
- Webpack

```js
/**
 * Import a file with the correct ES6 Module way:
 * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import
 */

import Cookie from './modules/Cookie.mjs';
import LazyLoadImages from './modules/LazyLoadImages.mjs';

/**
 * app.main
 */
const main = async (err) => {

    if (err) {
        // handle HMR errors
        console.error(err);
    }

    // application code
    app();

    /**
     * Initialize
     *
     * @see https://webpack.js.org/api/hot-module-replacement
     */
    import.meta.webpackHot?.accept(main);
};

/**
 * Add custom code inside this function
 */
const app = () => {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
        // Add your imported code here, for example: new defaultExport();
        new Cookie(true);
        new LazyLoadImages();
    });
}

/**
 * Run the application even if HMR is not enabled/used
 */
app();
```